# No animation with snapToGrid scrolling and tensileDragEnabled set to false

Tags: codenameone

I tried out snapToGrid which I thought might be just the simple solution one wants for lists with side-swipeable entries.
But if I disable tensileDragEnabled then there is no animation when the row snaps to the grid.
Is there a way to disable the tensile scrolling on the X-axis whilst having snapToGrid still animated?

Here's the code:

```
public class FormScrollingXY extends Form {
public FormScrollingXY() {
    setTitle("FormScrollingXY");
    setScrollable(false);
    setScrollableY(true);
    setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < 50; rowIndex++) {
        Container containerRow = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        containerRow.setSnapToGrid(true);
        containerRow.setScrollableX(true);
        containerRow.setTensileDragEnabled(false); // bad behaviour
        for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < 3; columnIndex++) {
            Container containerColumn = new Container(new FlowLayout()) {
                @Override
                protected Dimension calcPreferredSize() {
                    Dimension dimension = new Dimension(super.calcPreferredSize());
                    dimension.setWidth(containerRow.getWidth());
                    return dimension;
                }
            };
            containerColumn.add(new Label((rowIndex + 1) + "/" + (columnIndex + 1)));
            containerRow.add(containerColumn);
        }
        add(containerRow);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess but try doing this to see if it works around this:

```
Container containerRow = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.X_AXIS)) {
    public boolean isScrollableY() {
       return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Overriding isSrollableY() doesn't change anything - it's returns false anyway.
The thing is - apparently snapToGrid only works when tensileDraghEnabled is true. But I don't want tensile scrolling in the X-axis here. What I want ist snap-to-grid-behaviour with animation.

Comment: OK, I think I see the problem in the code. Snap to grid uses the tensile code to perform the actual animation so I added a special case for that. Should be a part of today's update.